# iOS: doubts about Alamofire vs AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-2, alamofire

I'm developing a new universal app (minimum iOS 7) and I want to use Swift (it's my second app with this new language).
In this app I need the AFNetworking framework, but I have some doubts about compatibility with the new version Alamofire. I know that there are some problems between Alamofire and iOS 7.
So, what do you suggest? Use Alamofire in this project or continue with AFNetworking?

Comment: I have developed iOS7 app in Swift using Alamofire, it works great.

Comment: really? I had a lot of trouble when I have to make the archive and validate app, you too?

Comment: Just get the Alamofire.swift file in your project, instead of dragging the whole Alamofire project.

Comment: and stop? no else? are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I am writing the explanation in answer

Comment: because I did it but when I write "import Alamofire" I have an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76493/discussion-between-sasquatch-and-nazz-areno).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just get the Alamofire.swift file in your project, instead of dragging the whole Alamofire project.
From [Alamofire Github page](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire):

> Source File
>
> For application targets that do not support embedded frameworks, such as iOS 7, Alamofire can be integrated by adding the Alamofire.swift source file directly into your project. Note that any calling conventions described in the 'Usage' section with the Alamofire prefix would instead omit it (for example, Alamofire.request becomes request), since this functionality is incorporated into the top-level namespace.